# iPad : Problem with orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4

After changing the orientation and try to write in textField.

This problem occurs only when I launch the app in Landscape mode to start with and then change the interface orientation to portrait.

My screen view moves slightly to right side.

I am not setting any frame for this, but still it moves at one side.

What should I do ?

[image: Problem with orientation]

Answer (score 0):

When I had this issue, I could solve it by setting the view's `bounds` in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` to their expected value.

Comment: -(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    
    if ([self isPadLandscape]) {
        [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768)];
    } else {
        [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,768,1024)];
    }
    
   
}

Comment: You should set the `bounds`, not the `frame`.

Comment: @Ben Alpert: I have tried to set `bounds` but still I am getting problem.

Answer (score 0):

select ur view and then set like below in the autoresizing arrow marks.note dim arrow and dark arrow marks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set it like on screen posted by madhu, but do it on window

x and y should be 0, in autosizing there should be checked upper and left "I"